# Style table CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to get these type of lines on a table

[image]

When I try to give the the `<table>` a "border right" property, it gives broken space between each cell.

Comment: They are called `border`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

border-right: 2px solid gray ;

HTML

```
<tr class="bordered">
```

CSS

```
.bordered
{
  border-right: 2px solid gray ; 
}
```

replace gray with any color you want like #cccccc

Comment: Actually `groove` might be better than `solid`

Comment: Thanks! Perfect! I looks good, was struggling with this for hours. Thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something similar like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Z2R/)

```
.td
{
border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is a vertical rule. Html has a horizontal rule

```
<hr>
```

However, it does not have a vertical rule. You can accomplish this with a bit of css though. For example

```
 <div style="border-left:1px solid #000;height:500px"></div>
```